# Using purrr's map together with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I want to use `%>%` and dplyr's `summarize` together with purrr's `map_dbl` to calculate means in a dataframe. For example I want to replicate the same result as the following code, but using `%>%` and  `summarize` :

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr) 
vars <- c("mpg", "hp")
vars <- set_names(vars)
mean_f <- function(df, var) {
  mean(df[[var]])
}

map_dbl(vars, ~mean_f(mtcars,.x))
```

I have tried this, but it only returns NAs:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

vars <- c("mpg", "hp")
vars <- set_names(vars)

mean_f <- function(var) {
  mtcars %>%
    summarise(mean_val = mean({{ var }}))
}

map_dbl(vars, ~mean_f(.x)$mean_val)
```

Comment: How about using `across`, i.e. `mtcars %>% summarise(across(all_of(vars), mean))`?

Comment: as stefan says, across is preferred; a purely technical solution for you is to replace the embrace `{{var}}` in your mean_f with the more explicit `!!sym(var)`

Answer (score 0):

```
dplyr::summarise(mtcars, across(all_of(c("mpg", "hp")), mean))
```

[Credit: stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76506023/using-purrrs-map-together-with-dplyr/76818975#comment134895151_76506023)